# Configuring Kaa (0.10.0) without an e-mail server

Tags: kaa

Is there anyway to configure Kaa *without* an e-mail service at first?  I don't want to configure that yet, but want to set up my test users, etc.

Anywhere in the conf/ folder or do I have to muck with the Java?

Answer (score 1):

You can register a user using [the Kaa server REST API](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Server-REST-APIs/#/User).

You're interested in the following methods:

- POST /api/auth/createKaaAdmin
- POST /api/admins/{tenantId}

The other possible solution is to use your existing email account.